# How can I do validation and use ..$setPristine(); in an AngularJS form?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
            <form class="form"
                  data-ng-submit="modalSubmit(modal.data)"
                  id="modal-body"
                  name="modalForm"
                  novalidate>
```

This works and when I click on a button of type submit then the modalSubmit function is called.

However I would like to do this in my controller:

```
$scope.modalForm.$setPristine();
```

But it gives an error saying:

```
has no method '$setPristine'
```

How I can I set the form to pristine? I did try adding `data-ng-form="modalForm"` but then I get
a message saying something to the effect of duplicate directive names.

I tried changing the form element to a DIV but then the clicking on the submit button does not call
the function

Here's an example (modified from another user) that shows what I am trying to do which is set values to pristine:

[plnkr.co/edit/LNanJdAggMLIgxii0cfv?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/LNanJdAggMLIgxii0cfv?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong there, only problem is you're referencing an old version of angular in which `$setPristine()` was not a feature. `$setPristine()` was added in 1.1.+, so reference a newer version of angular and you're good to go. See it working in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ksaQwyKcEV2BoDbiECz?p=preview), using 1.2.+.

If you can't upgrade, then a dirty workaround would be to loop through all inputs in the form and set their $dirty and $pristine values manually:

```
$scope.mp = function() {
  $scope.mainForm.$pristine=true;//clean main form
  $scope.mainForm.$dirty=false;
  angular.forEach($scope.mainForm,function(input){//clean all input controls
    if (input !== undefined && input.$dirty !== undefined) {
      input.$dirty=false;
      input.$pristine=true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your version of angular was old, 1.2.12 is the latest stable on the CDN.  But even it wouldn't allow $setPristine because of the HTML5 validation that was going on.

The biggest problem was you used `required` on the fields instead of `ng-required`.  The browser was doing the form validation for you instead of angular.  You could also add the `novalidate` attribute to the form tag.

http://plnkr.co/edit/l1mUCceSFMFFZWgGgL6u?p=preview

Comment: it was the `ng-required` that did it for me.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

it has already been implemented in this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview) you can use it this was as it has been demonstrated in the plnkr link.
As you can see from the above description, $setPristine only changes the state of the form (and thereby resets the css applied to each control in the form).

If you want to clear the values of each control, then you need to do for each in code.

Comment: The problem is I am getting a message saying there's no method $setPristine

Comment: it would be great if you post some other parts of your code, may be you have used it some what wrongly, may be that's why it's giving error to you. but still i put the ng-submit button in the form and on clicking the submit button it subimts that form and i have updated the plunkr too.http://plnkr.co/edit/JtDf5OjgWluWUF4CswtL?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LNanJdAggMLIgxii0cfv?p=preview